# What does the Flow mean?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, ipv6-transition

[image]

Above image explains how to communicate between IPv4 and IPv6 by tunneling..

I understand that concept by wrapping IPv6 datagram into iPv4 datagram..

But I do not understand what the 'Flow X' in the IPv6 datagram means?

Does anyone know that and can explain me?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A flow is usually a sequence of packets belonging together in some way. In IPv6 each packet has a flow label field that the sender can set to signal which packets belong together.